# ASP.NET WebApi attribute routing get controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using ASP.NET WebApi. And started using route attribute, but the problem is, when using attribute routing i can't get controller and action name in controller class. This is how i using:

```
[Route("GetInfo")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetInfoAction(){

  var controllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
  return Ok(controllerName );

}
```

And this not works, not getting controller name, but when commenting route attribute [Route("GetInfo")], getting controllerName.

Maybe someone knows why this happening and how to get controller name when using attribute routing?

Fixed, using like this:

```
var controllerName = ActionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
```

But strage this is, why routedata doesn't have this info. This can cause problems in the future.

Comment: try `[Route("/GetInfo")]`

Comment: no, this not good, getting also error. Found solution use like this: ActionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName but strangest thing is why routedata is emtpy...

Comment: Why do you need controllerName?

Comment: Show us the code for your controller.

Comment: Please show your `Global.asax` and `webApiConfig` codes.